# Remove Unicode UTF-8 character from string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I'm using excel vba to take a dataset and build an XML file.
The data comes in with some unicode characters inside some of the comments fields.
This causes problems for the XML.

Would like to strip out any of these non-printable characters during the vba process.
Thanks

Comment: XML usually works very well with UTF-8 or UTF-16. It might be that you just need to treat the data as UTF-16 because MS products typically use double byte unicode encoding.

Answer (score 0):

`WorksheetFunction.Clean()` should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.clean%28v=office.14%29.aspx